# Data connection between ActionScript and Java programs

Tags: java, actionscript-3

I need to send a byte stream from Java program to an ActionScript program. I'm looking for options. I searched some about reading/writing a file. filesystem package of AS3 is capable of that, but it requires Adobe Air and it really complicates my work. I will need to do lots of test and I'm planning to do it via a script. So filesystem package is not an option
Is pipe connection possible in AS3? Or simple socket connection in that way I can send bytes between Java and AS3 programs?

Answer (score 0):

OK so basically you want client-server interaction. You have many options it all depends on your needs. The most basic would be to use some form of the "[Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary)" class in AS3 to send and receive data as needed by the client. If you need more real-time data sent to the client you can look into the AS3 Socket class.